# Delete CR (carriage return) in a certain column

Tags: notepad++

As you can see in my attached picture, I have a CR (carriage return) at the end of each line:

[image: Screenshot of textfile]

Every second line consists of a line only with a CR. These lines are not necessary, but when I try to delete the CRs in the "empty lines", I am not successful.

Specifically, when I use `\r` to replace the CRs with blanks, my whole text is a mess.

When I use `\r\r` to replace the CRs, it is a mess again.

Any hints for me to solve this problem?

I am looking forward to help.

Comment: Do you want to make those lines empty or remove those lines fully?

Answer (score 0):

The "proper" Windows line ending is CRLF (Carriage Return Line Feed) or `\r\n`. So, as your first step, may want to use *Edit -> EOL Conversion -> Windows Format*.

If you want to simply remove the empty lines, you probably want to give *Edit -> Line Operations -> Remove Empty Lines* a try.

Answer (score 0):

When I take the file

[image]

And find=`\r\r`, replace=`\r`, with search mode=regular expression, I successfully change double `CR` into single `CR`.  That seems to be what you want.

[image]

Alternately, I got the same results by using find=`^\r`, replace= (empty), mode=regular expression.

If that's not the result you want, you'll have to be more specific